# How to select specific files for a Differential Release in InstallShield?

Tags: installshield-2012

I'm currently using InstallShield 2012 Spring Edition.

We have a product with some version that was released several months ago (say 1.0.1)

We now want to create a hot fix for it (say 1.0.1.1) and we want the media to include **specific** files that changed since the last release.

I've created a new Release and marked it as "Differential Media" and selected the "Include If Changed" option in "Object Difference". I then executed the Release Wizard and selected the specific Features that hold the new files.

The problem is that there are some other files that changed as well that we don't want to include in this release, but InstallShield recognizes them as files that were altered since the last release and adds them to the media.

Can we somehow select specific files to include in the update release?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, apparently, this is not possible. Or, at least I don't know of a way to do it.

What I've done to overcome this issue, is the following:

First, I've created several components and assigned them to a new Feature. All of the files in these components are static and marked as always copy. The Feature is set to be invisible.

Afterwards, I've created a new Release and configured it to be a differential release.
During the configuration, I've selected the feature that was created earlier.

This gives me the freedom to select specific files for the differential release and the ability to copy them to specific locations.

The drawback of this method is that for every new differential release, I need to create a new feature that will hold new components.